# How to calculate original loan amount without year terms?

Tags: ruby, math, finance

https://www.moneysmart.gov.au/tools-and-resources/calculators-and-apps/savings-goals-calculator

I want to get result like above calculator when I select:

I want to save: **6000**
I want to spend it: **As soon as possible**
Starting balance: **0**
Interest rate : **10%**
Regular savings: **1000 Monthly**

But I am getting not correct result using this code:

```
  loan = 6000.0
  interest = 10.0
  monthly_payment = 1000.0
  i =0.0
  record = []
  count = 1
  add_interst = 0.0
  while( loan>=0)
    i = interest/(100*12)*loan
    loan=i+(loan)-(monthly_payment);   
    add_interst = add_interst + i
  end
  puts add_interst
```

I am getting `181.42163384701658` which should be `168`. I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Why should it be 168? Can you please provide a bit of explanation?

Comment: according to reference link it should be 168 https://www.moneysmart.gov.au/tools-and-resources/calculators-and-apps/savings-goals-calculator

Comment: What is 'Regular savings' param?

Comment: Regular savings: 1000 Monthly

Comment: What does this line of code mean ` i = interest/(100*12)*loan` ?

Comment: changing my interest rate from annual to monthly.

Comment: Can you please explain *what* you want to calculate? How long it will take you to pay off the loan?

Comment: No I want to calculate interest amount

Comment: If you want to calculate interest, why are you doing it like paying off a loan?

Comment: because i don't know year or terms to find it. I have only original amount, interest rate and monthly payment.

Comment: Your interest amount should be  `loan_rate * loan_amount * loan_months`

Comment: daniel we don't have loan month in above code

Comment: @Daniel, that's not correct because any any given month the interest is calculated on the outstanding balance, not on the original amount of the loan.

Comment: user2372815, you say in the title that you want to calculate the "original loan amount", but in a comment you say, "I want to calculate interest amount." You refer to loans but the link takes us to a savings calculator. Are you surprised readers don't understand your question?

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't work because you are doing the opposite of what the link you reference is doing. What they are calculating is saving interest, what you are calculating is loan interest.

Basically, this is how you should define the variables.Also, as others have pointed out, it is good to use BigDecimal to calculate money:

```ruby
require 'bigdecimal'
balance = 0.to_d
interest = 10.to_d/1200.to_d
regular_saving = 1000;
goal =6000;
i = 0;
added_interest = 0
```

So, to correct things, you have to start from the `starting balance` (i.e 0) and start incrementing. Something like this:

```
while balance < goal
    balance += regular_saving;
    i  = balance * (interest);
    balance +=i;
    added_interest+=i;
end
```

Note also, that in the last year you don't need to pay the full saving amount. You only need to pay to reach the goal. For that, you need to add a conditional statement to check `goal - balance < regular_saving`. If this was the case, the interest should be calculated in terms of the balance that should be paid (slightly less than the goal).

Comment: [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)